# Xbox something's wrong

Tags: xbox-360

I downloaded my friends accounts and downloaded some games. I would sign out after the download finished then sign into my account. But when I click the game to play it says it won't launch. Unless I'm on the account that bought it.

The first time I downloaded a profile it worked perfectly and I can still download and play games from him. But no other ones let me play.

Comment: A couple of years ago, my friend bought the original BioShock game digitally. His Xbox 360 was broken, so he used mine. I found that if his profile launched the game and I switched profiles while on the start screen, I could use my profile to play the game and earn the achievement I was missing. This may have been since patched, but I can't find anything conclusive. Give it a try, and if it works, I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If Xbox is letting you play a game from a different account, it is a bug. You can not okay a game your account does not own, even if you have a separate account logged into the system that does.

I can confirm this also counts if your mate is signed in, and you are trying to join as a second player.

Also, if the system detects the console isn't the last console the account signed in from, it will still require a password, so you can not just leave the account signed in.

I've tried what your doing to play 2 player at a mates, I've tried "enabling" my mates to play my games and I've also tried enabling a mates "always-offline" console.

Trust me, it sucks, but it won't work.